# Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt

Tags: linux, mac, java

I am on the following:

```
macOS Monterey
version 12.3.1
```

And I am trying to intsall `pyenv` with the following:

```
sudo apt install -y curl && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/0xboz/install_pyenv_on_debian/master/install.sh | bash
```

However, I get the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

I have install Java, but the error still occurs.

Comment: You have MacOS but are trying to install something for Debian. It might be worth going back a couple of steps and explaining why you need this particular thing and why you expect it to work on a completely different platform.

Comment: https://www.mediaglasses.blog/2021/10/30/managing-python-on-macos-monterey/ suggests that `brew install pyenv` might be a more appropriate command.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=macos%20install%20pyenv